# How to import stripe module in Airflow dag

Tags: python, stripe-payments, airflow

I'm trying to write DAG which will export stripe transactions.

I have python script which use stripe module and it works perfectly on my local computer and in AWS pipeline. But when I try to add stripe module in dag (with

> `import stripe`

), I receive error:

```
 File "/opt/airflow/analytics-pipelines/dags/stripe_to_s3.py", line 6, in <module>
    import stripe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe'
```

How could I use this module in DAG?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your Airflow installation has `stripe` package installed. Depending on how your airlfow deployment it might be:

1. installing stripe (and restarting airflow in virtualenv where it is installed) - if airflow is installed in a virtualenv
2. Building custom image and adding `stripe` package if you are using airflow installed via docker images or Kubernetes/Helm Chart: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#why-custom-image
3. INstalling custom requirements via service specicfic mechanisms if you use Airflow-as-servic (for example Astronomer, MWAA or Cloud Composer) - each of those services has a custom way of adding new dependencies.